# How to change color of background in RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to change background color of item in recyclerview but this doesn't work. I am not sure why. Could it be problem with constraint layout? I tried several tutorials and similar question but at this moment I am really confused.

**Adapter**

```
class ExampleAdapter(private val exampleList: List<ExampleItem>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>()
{
    var onItemClick: ((ExampleItem, Int) -> Unit)? = null
    var onItemLongClick: ((ExampleItem) -> Boolean)? = null
    var selected_item: Int = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    //var examples: List<ExampleItem> = emptyList()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recy, parent, false)
        return ExampleViewHolder(itemView)

    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int){
        val currentItem = exampleList[position]
        holder.tv_ID.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.tv_NAME.text = currentItem.name   
        
        if (position == selected_item){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7ADE4A"))            
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0CC62"))
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return exampleList.size
    }
    inner class ExampleViewHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tv_ID: TextView = itemView.tv_ID
        val tv_NAME: TextView = itemView.tv_NAME
        
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                onItemClick?.invoke(exampleList[absoluteAdapterPosition], absoluteAdapterPosition)
                itemView.setSelected(true)
                notifyItemChanged(selected_item)
                selected_item = absoluteAdapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(selected_item)                
                }
            }
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
                onItemLongClick?.invoke(exampleList[absoluteAdapterPosition])
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using ConstraintLayout and ScrollView in layout xml. RecyclerView is in TableLayout. Should it be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change-

```
var selected_item: Int = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
```

To this-

```
var selected_item: Int = 0
```

somehow RecyclerView.NO_POSITION this value updates automatically and your **selected_item** is always equal to your current item position.

Comment: I change it, like you wrote it but still doesn't work. I changed code like this - and it works. But just for one cell, not for all lineif (position == selected_item){
            holder.tv_NAME.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            
        } else {
            holder.tv_NAME.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            
        }

Comment: As I get your point you want to set GREEN for selected items and for all rest items want to set WHITE in background. So every time when you select an item you need to update adapter with by **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**

Answer (score 1):

In above code, you are setting color based on condition

```
 position == selected_item
```

But selected_item is being updated in viewholder click listener. Means only after we click item,selected_item will be updated.Till then it will be **RecyclerView.NO_POSITION** and when onBindViewHolder gets called it will be NO_POSITION.

So, you can handle background color inside onClickListener present inside ViewHolder.